# making a circle with 3 random points and jointing them togheter to make a triangle

Tags: java, processing

making a circle with 3 random points with small elipses on them and making a triangle with those small elipses/points
i get a line or a broken triangle, i found out that the coords on the triangle has to have 1 number that is different like `triangle(500, 500, 200 ,200 ,100 , 50);`
but i cannot find a something that fixes that

```java
int num = 3;
float[] numbers = new float[6];
int count = 0;

void setup(){
    size(880,880);
    translate(width/2,height/2);
    ellipse(0, 0, 512, 512);
    fill(256,100,0);
    ellipse(0, 0, 5, 5);
}

void draw(){
    float r = random(0, 256);
    float s = random(0, 256);
    fill(0,100,256);

    translate(width/2,height/2);
    if (count < 3)
    {
        ellipse(256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + r ),256*sin(TWO_PI/float(1) + r),10,10);
        stroke(100,256,0);
        numbers[count] = r;
        count++;
        numbers[count] = s;
    }
    else if (count == num)
    {
        beginShape();
        vertex(256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[0]),256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[0]));
        vertex(256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[1]),256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[1]));
        vertex(256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[4]),256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[5]));
        endShape(CLOSE);
        //triangle  (256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[0]),256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[0]),256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[1]),256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[1]),256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[2]),256*cos(TWO_PI/float(1) + numbers[2]));
        count++;
    }
}

void keyPressed() {
    count = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the points by points of the triangle by an random angle:

```java
float angle = random(0, 360);

float x = 256*cos(angle);
float y = 256*sin(angle);
```

Store the points of the triangle to an array:

```java
numbers[count*2] = x;
numbers[count*2+1] = y;
count++;
```

Now a triangle can by drawn with ease:

```java
 triangle(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4], numbers[5] );
```

Full `draw` function:

[image]

```java
void draw(){
    
    if (count == 0 )
    {
        for (int i=0; i < 3; ++i ) {
            float angle = random(0, 360);
            numbers[i*2]   = 256*cos(angle);
            numbers[i*2+1] = 256*sin(angle);
        }
        count = 3;           
    }
    
    translate(width/2,height/2);
    
    background(160);
    fill(255);
    ellipse(0, 0, 512, 512);
    fill(255,100,0);
    ellipse(0, 0, 5, 5);
    
    fill(0,100,255);
    ellipse(numbers[0], numbers[1], 10, 10);
    ellipse(numbers[2], numbers[3], 10, 10);
    ellipse(numbers[4], numbers[5], 10, 10);
    
    stroke(100,256,0);
    triangle(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3], numbers[4], numbers[5] );
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/graphics-snippets/example/p5.js/p5js_circle_3_points.html)</kbd>